# Someone who parts their hair to cover their bald head

Tags: synonyms

I hope you can help me find one or more adjectives that describe a person who parts their hair in a way to cover the bald part of their head whether it is a positive or a negative word.
Thanks

Comment: The action, or hairdo, is called a [comb-over](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/combover).

Comment: As far as I know there's no word for the person; but the hairdo is called a 'combover'.

Comment: How to disguise a bald spot: seven tips and tricks : http://www.telegraph.co.uk/men/style/how-to-disguise-a-bald-spot-seven-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: Before any more people answer with _comb-over_ or the equivalent, please note that the OP is asking for a) an adjective, and b) a word to describe the _person_.

Comment: I doubt there is an established word meaning "comb-overer".

Comment: I think the preferred construction is "comber-overer". As long as we're making words up.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly negative term is a [comb-over](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/comb-over).

> a hairstyle in which long strands of hair from the side of the head are swept over the scalp to cover a bald patch

I have usually seen it with a negative connotation built in: a bad comb-over.

Comment: I've yet to see a *good* comb-over. The connotation is so bad, the phrase borders on redundancy.

Comment: Point taken, André. In searching for comb-over, related searches brought up a (positive) "model comb over" and a hairstyle called a "cut comb over"  (also positive).

Comment: Christian Bale's character Irving Rosenfeld in the movie [American Hustle](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1800241/) had a pretty amazing comb-over.  This is not to say that the comb-over wasn't a metaphor for his con man (bad) behavior.

Comment: @AndreAngelo or perhaps you've seen many that were so well-done you didn't notice. :]

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the conversation, the noun would be [**comb–over**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comb-over).

> **comb-over** *n.* an arrangement of hair on a balding man in which hair from the side of the head is combed over the bald spot

For adjectives, you can describe their hair as **thin**, **wispy**, **baldheaded**(a tad on the nose), or **bare**.

If you would like to lean more towards the technical side, go for **[glabrous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glabrous)**.

> **glabrous** *adj.* having a surface devoid of hair or pubescence.

For me, I tell them that they're lucky: they get to save money on shampoo and call it a day. Not an adjective, but fun none the less.

Answer (score 0):

You might describe a person with such hair as combed-over.

Also vain, defined by MW as:

> ```
> 1:  having no real value :  idle, worthless vain pretensions
> 2:  marked by futility or ineffectualness :  unsuccessful, useless vain efforts to escape
> 3  archaic :  foolish, silly
> 4:  having or showing undue or excessive pride in one's appearance or achievements :  conceited
> ```

"Vain" gets at the idea of pointlessness in this effort to conceal the loss of hair.

On the other hand, most people make some effort at appearances--haircuts, beard trimming, face lifts, make-up, toupees, and so forth.  Perhaps it is the pointlessness of the comb-over that inspires contempt rather than admiration for the effort.